# More than one modal box on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Edit**

I have updated all the code in this question.

**Question**

I have been trying to get more than one modal box to work a single page.

I can get one to work but I can't replicate it so that two will open (I want there to be three modal boxes  to in the end?

This is the button that is being called to open the first modal;

```
    <button id="myHistoryBtn" class="myAboutBtn">more</button>
```

This is the second one;

```
<button id="myAboutBtn" class="myAboutBtn">more</button>
```

This is the modal structure that I am using

```
<div id="myHistoryModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-container">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <span class="modalclose">×</span>
                <h1>sstory</h1>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the second one

```
<div id="myAboutModal" class="modal2">

          <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-container">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <span class="Aboutclose" id="close">×</span>
                <h1>AAAAAstory</h1>
              </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Then this is the JavaScript that is making everything work.

```
         // Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myHistoryModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myHistoryBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("modalclose")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
        main.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
        main.style.display = "flex";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
                main.style.display = "flex";
    }
}
```

Here is the JavaScript to get the other modal box to work.

```
// Get the modal
var about = document.getElementById('myAboutModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var Abtn = document.getElementById("myAboutBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var Aspan = document.getElementById("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
Abtn.onclick = function(event) {
    about.style.display = "block";
        main.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
Aspan.onclick = function() {
    about.style.display = "none";
    main.style.display = "flex";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function() {
    if (event.target == about) {
        about.style.display = "none";
                main.style.display = "flex";
    }
}
```

I think I am going insane as it all starting to muddle now. Once I try to have more than one modal box it.

I gave it one more go and I sort have got it to work (sort of)

One of the modal box appears when I click the button but won't disappear on close (just stays there)

When I click the other modal box button it hides content but doesn't show the modal box?

Heres a link of what I am working on. I have taken out the code that makes the other modal boxes to work to show you what meant to happen when you click on the more button.

http://www.periodictablesearch.zackreid.com/pages/Carbon.html

This is just confusing me now. I have renamed everything on the second set of JavaScript that makes the second button to work but still nothing.

**Edit**

So I have now got them to appear and but one is still broken a bit.

http://www.periodictablesearch.zackreid.com/pages/Carbon.html

Then second modal box appears but it won't hide/ close done when using the button our clicking outside the modal box.

**Edit**

I have now gotten the second modal to close when clicking of the window. Just need to make the button work? Is anyone interested? Should I update my code?

Comment: "The modal window is a child window that requires users to interact with it before it can return to operating the parent application, thus preventing the workflow on the application main window." Basically, you can't have more than one "modal" box on a page, by definition, because each one is supposed to be in focus until an action is performed on that box.

Comment: @Dudebird47 They aren't meant to be open at the same time.. They are modal boxes which contain more content for different sections of the page. So you would only ever open on up at a time. Sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: I see.  I didn't understand that at first. I'll delete my comment if you feel like it doesn't add anything... Sorry to be that guy!

Comment: @Dudebird47 Nahh its all cool :)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to change the name of second box to

```
var myAboutModal = document.getElementById('myAboutModal');
var myAboutBtn = document.getElementById("myAboutsBtn");
```

and register the `onclick` to `myAboutBtn` like:

```
myAboutBtn.onclick = function() {
  myAboutModal.style.display = "block";
  main.style.display = "none";
}
```

Otherwise it will end up mess with the first `btn` and `modal` variable

And same with the `span` variable. By the way, the span may need to use the `id` instead of the classname, because  `getElementsByClassName("close")[0];` is always the first span in the document, may never give you the second span you want for the second modal

For the close btn, you can add event listener to all close button without the need to add them one by one

```
var closeBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("modalclose");
for(var i=0; i< closeBtns.length; i++) {
   closeBtns[i].onclick = function() {
       modal.style.display = "none";
       about.style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

To close modal when click outside of it, you need to check if the target is not any of the modal, not the trigger modal buttons, not the `modal-container`, not the `modal-content` and not any content inside of `modal-content`

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target != modal && event.target != about && event.target != btn && event.target != Abtn && event.target.className != "modal-container" && event.target.className != "modal-content" && event.target.parentNode.className != "modal-content") {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        about.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

I am not sure what you want to do with the `main.style.display = "flex"`. In most cases, there is no need to set any style regarding the `main`, assuming the `main` is the html `<body>`

A working jsfiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/yg88rvgq/1/

Comment: I will give this a go now. Just to make sure I took out the second modal box, to see if the first one actually works (it does)

Comment: I just tried this and it sort of works now just the button to close the second modal box isn't working :/

Comment: well, you mess up the code s little bit `var Aspan = document.getElementById("close")[0];` should be `getElementById("close")` without the `[0]`, because id returns one object, but  `getElementsByClassName` will return an array of objects. So you just need to change it, it will give you the `close` btn you want

Comment: Thanks that made them mostly work now.. They are not closing done when clicking outside of the modal. But I might just get rid of that feature :) thanks again

Comment: just realised that its only ever working for the newest modal box that I add to the script :/ I must just be running the JavaScript for that modal box for the other two..

Comment: Another approach would be use className for all `close` button. like `closeBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("modalclose")`, but run define a function to check each of them when you click on one of them. This is a approach what jquery do. function added in the answer